# Reduce brightness of white color (Whitepoint) on MacBook 2020 (eye strain, pain)

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My eyes hurt when I work with a MacBook. My eyes perceive other displays well.

The same problem was with my iPhone, my eyes hurt and I turned on "Reduce Whitepoint" (this is available only on iOS) and now I want to do the same thing on my MacBook, but I just can't figure out how to lower the brightness of the white color.

I went into the color calibration settings and there you can change the color (for example, more yellow or blue), but this is not at all like on the iPhone.

[image: Screenshot of Reduce White Point setting on iPhone]
(not my screenshot)

Answer (score 4):

There are [at least] two ways to achieve this, one temporary, one 'permanent'.

This assumes you need this for comfort… as any adjustment of this type is not going to be useful if you need a professional colour-calibrated workflow, as it makes all the colours you see "wrong".

The temporary method is in System Preferences > Displays > Night Shift
Set to Manual:Turn On Until Tomorrow, then use the slider below to determine the amount of hue-shift.
This will, of course, reset every morning.

[image]

*A late thought* - you could maybe do this on the Night Shift Schedule mode - set it to on all the time except five minutes when you'll always be asleep - e.g. 01:05 to 01:00 - I haven't tested how it might treat a 'wrap-around' timer like this, so you'd have to test it.

[image]

To do this 'permanently' [you can switch back whenever you want, but it will stick until you do] Then in System Preferences > Displays > Colour & click Calibrate…
In the following window, step through the pages  - you can ignore everything else until you get to Target White Point.
This step will allow you to dial in a very similar hue-shift that Night Mode does.
Disable 'Use Native white point' then drag the slider left… D65 is roughly 'normal daylight' & D50 is 'page white'.
Click through til the end of the sequence then save with a memorable name & apply it.
You will then have one more option in your Display profile list - your new 'redder' display profile. You can switch whenever you like. Each will be remembered until you change your mind.

[image]

<sup>Image shows Advanced options - you don't need to enable these, you only need Target white point</sup>

Comment: Calibrating your own Display Profile is the obvious solution. Using Night Shift is a hack.

Comment: To calibrate you need $£€ 250 of hardware. If you're not doing any task that needs colour management, the hack is 'good enough'.

Comment: I'm talking about using the Display Calibrator Assistant, which requires no hardware.

Comment: @benwiggy - the OP isn't asking about calibration in any way, shape or form. I added the paragraph to my answer covering calibration *just in case* it may impact any colour workflow.

Comment: I'm essentially just saying "I'd go with the second bit".

Comment: Thanks! D60 helped me to relieve the discomfort after upgrading from MBP 2017 to M1 MBP 2020.

Comment: Turning on night shift permanently and turning down the color temperature made the whites more tolerable for me on a M1 Pro Mac 2021.

Answer (score 1):

(Posting this as an answer, although it doesn't get you the full way there, because I want to include the screenshot)

Color Profiles are definitely powerful enough to do this, and a lot more. Once you create a custom profile, it is saved in `/Users/bohdan/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/my_profile.icc`. The following is what you get by opening the file, and it shows the parameter space of these profiles.

[image: ICC Profile View]

The bad news is that the ColorSync Utility doesn't allow editing these files. And, also, that I cannot tell you *how* exactly you would want to change it. But I do remember working on these profiles with some editor bundled with Adobe products, and it was essentially the same as adjusting the curves Photos.app. So finding an editor for icc would be promising.

To just get an idea if this might work, you may also want to click through all the default profiles. I did use one that was definitely not intended for my screen for a while because had a soothing cinema-like low-contrast effect.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across something else that might be worth a try: there are color filters in *Accessibility*. They are intended for various specific visual impairments, but maybe one of them just happens to work for your purpose. The *Colour Tint* filter (pictured), for example, definitely succeeds in blunting whites (but also tints all other colors). [image: accessibility Colour filters]